# Problem when moving TableRow within TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout

I am trying to dynmically move several rows around at once within a specific view based on user input.

The use-case is that the user picks an option and based on the option, certain rows are show/hidden and the rows need to be rearranged to make sense to the user.

The `TableLayout` is instantiated in `XML`, but the `TableRow` and it's layout(s) are instantiated in code. I have tried several different methods, with varying levels of success.

Code which works for hiding/disabling properly:

```
private void updateTimeRow(TargetType goalTarget)
{
    TableRow timeRow = (TableRow)this.findViewById(timeId + 100);
    EditText timeText = (EditText)this.findViewById(timeId);
    if (goalTarget == TargetType.daysRowedWeek
            || goalTarget == TargetType.metersDay
            || goalTarget == TargetType.metersSeason
            || goalTarget == TargetType.metersWeek)
    {
        timeRow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        timeRow.setEnabled(false);
        timeText.setEnabled(false);
    }
    else if (goalTarget == TargetType.splitForDistance
            || goalTarget == TargetType.unknown)
    {
        setTimeText(currentTarget.recalcTime().toString());
        timeRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        timeRow.setEnabled(false);
        timeText.setEnabled(false);
    }
    else
    {
        timeRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        timeRow.setEnabled(true);
        timeText.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Based on questions answered here, I tried removing/re-adding rows, with this piece of code:

```
    int rowNum = -1;
    tableLayout.removeView(timeRow);
    switch (goalTarget)
    {
    case unknown:
    case timeForDistance:
        rowNum = 2;
        break;
    case splitForDistance:
        rowNum = 4;
        break;
    case splitForTime:
        rowNum = 3;
        break;
    }
    tableLayout.addView(timeRow, rowNum);
```

Two things break here:

- The disable code fails (whether this code is run before of after the enable/disable code above
- The rows in my layout get all screwed up.

So, how do I move the rows around dynamically, while properly hiding/showing/enabling/disabling the different rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of frustrating trial and error, I finally figured out the only way to do this with solid results:

I had to adjust the way my UI was updating, to a 3-step process:
 - Update the values for the Inputs (enforces formatting, re-calcs, etc)
 - Re-layout the rows
 - Enable/disable the different inputs based on the selections

The nuts and bolts is that anytime the `goalTarget` changes I have to remove all of the `TableRow`s from the `TableLayout` and add

them back in the correct order, with the appropriate row numbers as part of the `addView()` call.

This is definitely not the prettiest way I could see it being done, but apparently the `TableLayout` doesn't like you just trying

to move things around one at a time.